# No heist prerequisites are showing up in GTA V

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've done the trash truck mission for the blitz play heist but nothing is showing up for anything of the other heist prerequisites. I've played and beaten this before but having issues now is really frustrating. Someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

Those prerequisites are only available at certain times of the day, just play around with the different characters for a bit and if none still show up then your game might be bugged, try reverting to an earlier save if you have one available or try going into gta online then back out. Hopefully you won't have to start your game again, good luck!